# AWS cron expression OK, lambda not triggered

Tags: aws-lambda, cron

I have set the following cron expression in AWS (CloudWatch trigger).

`0 */5 7-12,1pm-11pm ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI`

In expression generator, I get for very similar expresssion (7-23 intead of the hours )

`At second :00, every 5 minutes starting at minute :00, every hour between 07am and 23pm, on every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday, every month`
as expected.

However, it is not triggered. I don't see anything in the log.
[image: The expression is wrong somehow]

Why is that? (trigger is enabled of course)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the expression wasn't right.

It considers minutes only and the `*/5` confused it too maybe. Not sure about the `*` at the end.

`0/5 7-23 ? * MON-FRI *` - this works

To debug triggers, there is "Rules" section in the log service, where you can see the next executions.

Comment: This is a difference compared to the expression generator of cron

Answer (score 2):

When you create CloudWatch Event Rule, or EventBridge Event Rule (is what AWS calls these days) and select Lambda function as target, there are 2 main points that you need to consider:

1. CRON SCHEDULE

You need to specify the cron schedule and this schedule timezone is **UTC+0**.

I assume that you are in different timezone and observe there is not any triggers since the next trigger time has not been reached yet.

2. RESOUCE-BASED POLICY

There is another chance that you need to check is about permissions, you need to concern is Lambda function's `Resource Based Policy`.

Go to AWS Console, you can check your Lambda's permission tab and review your permissions which is required to allow your Event Rule triggers.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSEvents",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:function:<FUNCTION_NAME>",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:rule/<RULE_NAME>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I expect it to be in UTC.

Comment: Invocation graph empty, log empty. Started it 3 hours ago

Comment: I thought maybe the 7-12 is taken to be pm as well

Comment: I thought you may misunderstand about the timezone but it is not, then my next concern is about your Lambda function permissions, you can check out my update answer as above :D

Comment: Yes, it is as you mentioned. The sid is longer

Answer (score 0):

Since the CRON expression is in UTC time format. Could you please check if there is any time difference b/w your standard time and UTC time?

And change the expression accordingly.